# How can I extract information from "google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.evaluation.Evaluationt"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am new in the world of cloud and I am trying to use the DOCUMENT AI from GOOGLE but I stucked on how to extract information like precision, accuracy and others from a training evaluation. Here is the code to retrieve an specific evaluation performed on a custom processor.

```
def get_evaluation_sample(project_id: str, location: str, processor_id: str, 
                          processor_version_id: str, evaluation_id: str) -> None:

    opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")
    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)

    evaluation_name = client.evaluation_path(project_id, location, processor_id,
                                             processor_version_id, evaluation_id)

    evaluation = client.get_evaluation(name=evaluation_name)
    #save as .pkl
    save_document("bucket", evaluation, "evaluation_name")
```

This code basically retrieve the information of an existing model evaluation and save as .pkl in a gcp bucket. Until here ok. After that I download this .pkl open on VSCode and try to extract information (unsuccessfully). Even de documentation is no clear to me. My main objective is to extract at least the f1 score. Here some add informations:

```
  type(evaluation): google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.evaluation.Evaluation
  dir(evaulation): ['ConfidenceLevelMetrics', 'Counters', 'EntityMetricsEntry', 'Metrics', 
                    'MultiConfidenceMetrics', '__bool__', '__class__', '__contains__', 
                    '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', 
                    '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', 
                    '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', 
                    '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
                    '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
                    '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'all_entities_metrics', 
                    'create_time','document_counters', 'entity_metrics', 'kms_key_name', 
                    'kms_key_version_name', 'name']
```

If I go ahead to Metrics (evaluation.Metrics) we have:

```
type(evaluation.Metrics): proto.message.MessageMeta
dir(evaluation.Metrics): ['__abstractmethods__', '__base__', '__bases__', 
                          '__basicsize__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', 
                          '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
                          '__flags__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
                          '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', 
                          '__instancecheck__', '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__', 
                          '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', 
                          '__prepare__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
                          '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
                          '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__', 
                          '__text_signature__', '__weakrefoffset__', 'copy_from', 
                          'deserialize', 'from_json', 'meta', 'mro', 'pb', 'serialize', 
                          'to_dict', 'to_json', 'wrap']
```

But I am lost on how to use 'copy_from', 'deserialize', 'from_json', 'meta', 'mro', 'pb', 'serialize', 'to_dict', 'to_json', 'wrap' every try give an error. Can anyone explain me how to use it and extract the information. As the documentation mention the information I need is here.
Here are some add documentation I consulted

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.documentai.v1#google.cloud.documentai.v1.Evaluation.Metrics

I do not know how to do this, but anyone need I can provide the .pkl file.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION fOR @Holt Skinner:
I tried to reach the f1_score using

```
f1_score_exact = evaluation.all_entities_metrics.confidence_level_metrics_exact.metrics.f1_score
```

but an error raised:

```
'RepeatedComposite' object has no attribute 'metrics'
```

This attempt was performed in a function in gcp. I print the dir() of each step into f1_score on evaluation object:

```
dir(evaluation)
['ConfidenceLevelMetrics', 'Counters', 'EntityMetricsEntry', 'Metrics', 'MultiConfidenceMetrics', '__bool__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'all_entities_metrics', 'create_time', 'document_counters', 'entity_metrics', 'kms_key_name', 'kms_key_version_name', 'name']

dir(evaluation.all_entities_metrics)
 ['MetricsType', '__bool__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'auprc', 'auprc_exact', 'confidence_level_metrics', 'confidence_level_metrics_exact', 'estimated_calibration_error', 'estimated_calibration_error_exact', 'metrics_type']

dir(evaluation.all_entities_metrics.confidence_level_metrics_exact)
['__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__class_getitem__', '__contains__', '__copy__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_abc_impl', '_marshal', '_pb', '_pb_type', '_proto_type', 'append', 'clear', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pb', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

But the f1_score exist, and is 0.551 (it is possible to see it in the UI of document ai)

[image: documentai_ui_f1_score]

Here is the code in the funcion:
[image: function_code]

I do not know why the f1_score appear in the UI but not by command line over the object evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, your main goal is to save and extract the information from the [`Evaluation.metrics`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.documentai.v1#google.cloud.documentai.v1.Evaluation.Metrics) field. Google APIs use [Protocol buffers](https://protobuf.dev/) to transfer data, and each client library, such as Python are wrappers on top of the RPC calls. The objects created by these client libraries shouldn't be "pickled" the same way as other objects.

I would recommend saving the Evaluation objects as JSON format in Cloud Storage, which can then be accessed as Python Objects.

Example:

```py
from google.cloud import documentai

def get_evaluation_sample(project_id: str, location: str, processor_id: str, 
                          processor_version_id: str, evaluation_id: str) -> None:

    opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")
    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)

    evaluation_name = client.evaluation_path(project_id, location, processor_id,
                                             processor_version_id, evaluation_id)

    evaluation = client.get_evaluation(name=evaluation_name)
    # Instead of .pkl, export as JSON
    json_string = documentai.Evaluation.to_json(evaluation)
    # Upload JSON to Cloud Storage
```

Then to get the JSON as a Python object:

```py
from google.cloud import documentai

json_string = get_from_cloud_storage() # Insert your method here
evaluation = documentai.Evaluation.from_json(json_string)
print(evaluation) # You can access the evaluation fields on this object
```

**Edit:** The F1 Score for the full evaluation is deeply nested in the `Evaluation` object, depending on which metric you want to access.

This page has the Python client library documentation for the `Evaluation` class which includes all of the fields available.

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.Evaluation

You should be able to access the `f1_score` through:

```py
# For metrics with Fuzzy Matching
f1_score_fuzzy = evaluation.all_entities_metrics[index].confidence_level_metrics[index].metrics.f1_score

# For metrics with exact matching only
f1_score_exact = evaluation.all_entities_metrics[index].confidence_level_metrics_exact[index].metrics.f1_score
```

If these fields are empty, then it's possible these aren't being populated by the API, and that will require further investigating.

Comment: Hello @Holt Skinner, thanks for he answer, this solve my problem in parts, this enable me to save the evaluation as json, but the json only has information specific to each label and confidence level. What I need is to extract the information that is a summary of all operation, as presented in https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.documentai.v1#google.cloud.documentai.v1.Evaluation.Metrics, e. g. I need to extrac evaluation.Metrics.f1_score but I can't reach this field using .pkl, neither using the solution you proposed. Do you know how I can reach this value?

Comment: Updated answer with additional context

Comment: Hello @Holt Skinner, thanks again, but I didnot reach the f1_score yet. I add more details  and updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my sample. Some of those fields are arrays and need indexes to access the fields.

You might also need to loop through some of those array fields to get the right metric you're looking for.

Comment: you are right, I tried this but sometimes the result is none/empty and sometimes it even exists, that way my doubt on how to access these metrics.